# How to add delay between loop python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to ask , i try with my coding but it still not working, i want to execute 2 loop with delay and print each word with delay.

here my coding

```
import threading,time

def func_name1():
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for i in fruits:
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i)

def func_name2():
fruits2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
for i in fruits2:
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i)

f1 = threading.Thread(target=func_name1)
f2 = threading.Thread(target=func_name2)
f1.start()
time.sleep(2)
f2.start()
```

output like this

```
apple
1
banana
2
cherry
3
```

i want scenario like this

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to properly indent your python code

Comment: Also please include the actual output. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: the output is like that, but i want when execute loop 1 print : apple , then delay , after that execute second loop print : 1 , {delay} , and back to execute first loop.

Comment: Output is like what? You need to [edit] your post to include the current output

Comment: @AchmadRivaldi FWIW, You could do that with one function instead of two.

Comment: look my scenario , i already edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

I have updated my code Now it matches your scenario. The whole Script takes approximatly `25.03` seconds.

```
def func_name1():
    fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
    a = 0
    for i in fruits:
        a += 1
        print(i)
        if a == len(fruits):
            return
        time.sleep(10)

def func_name2():
    fruits2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
    a = 0
    for i in fruits2:
        a +=1
        print(i)
        if a==len(fruits2):
            return
        time.sleep(10)

f1 = threading.Thread(target=func_name1)
f2 = threading.Thread(target=func_name2)
f1.start()
time.sleep(5)
f2.start()
```

```
apple
1
banana
2
cherry
3
```

---

To check the whole execution time. Use this code.

```
import threading,time

t = time.time()

def func_name1():
    fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
    a = 0
    for i in fruits:
        a += 1
        print(i)
        if a == len(fruits):
            return
        time.sleep(10)

def func_name2():
    fruits2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
    a = 0
    for i in fruits2:
        a +=1
        print(i)
        if a==len(fruits2):
            return
        time.sleep(10)

f1 = threading.Thread(target=func_name1)
f2 = threading.Thread(target=func_name2)
f1.start()
time.sleep(5)
f2.start()

f2.join()

print(time.time() - t)
```